# is id necessary in a list?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list, indexing

I have a basic question regarding MongoDB database design: 1 or 2 is a better designs?

One article document contains several lists, such as reference list, content list. Using a Reference Object as an example, it can be designed to only have one field (ref_content) or two fields (ref_id, ref_content).

Technically I don't need the field of ref_id since I can get away by using the list index instead. What do you think? -- Wendy

1. ref_content

or

2. ref_content, ref_id

Comment: I think it depends on how you are going to use them.

Comment: I decided to not have the id in Mongodb.